# Form submission adds a <br> in front of the beginning text in the form

Tags: php, sql-server

Ok, I am using a PHP editing form (previous person built) that submits data into an MSSQL database this works fine however when the information is submitted into the database and later retrieved the the form page (for editing) there is a `<br>` at the beginning of the text. If the fields start with a `<ul>` that `<br>` is not inserted. I have been trying to figure out how to stop this. One thing I tried ends up removing all `<br>` in the text which makes the formatting disappear, How can I keep it from inserting the `<br>` at the top but keeping the `<br>` everywhere else? here is the code I have: ( I am giving you everything up to the first field where I have the issue appear)

```
function fromhtml ($x) {
  $x = preg_replace("/<p>/i","\n\n",$x);
  //$x = preg_replace("/<br>/i","\n",$x);
  $x = preg_replace("/<li>/i","\n<li>",$x);

  return $x;
}

$PHP_SELF = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];


$course_id = @$_GET["course"];

if ($course_id == "") {

$sqlquery = "SELECT id, title, goals, outline, reference, deliverymode, updated2 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), updated, 120)
FROM courses WHERE division_id = '$division_id' ORDER by id";


$result = mssql_query($sqlquery);
$number = mssql_num_rows($result);

print "<table border=1 id=\"content_table\"><tr><th>ID</th><th>Title</th><th>Status</th><th>Last modified</th></tr>\n";

$i = 0;
while ($number > $i) {

        $course_id =  mssql_result($result,$i,"id");
    $reference = mssql_result($result,$i,"reference");
    $updated = mssql_result($result,$i,"updated2");

    print "<tr><td>";
    if ($reference == "") {
            print "<a href=$PHP_SELF?division=$division_id&course=$course_id>$course_id</a>";
    } else {
            print "$course_id";
    }
    print "</td><td>";
        print mssql_result($result,$i,"title");
    print "</td><td>";
    if ($reference == "") {
        if ( (mssql_result($result,$i,"goals")=="") and (mssql_result($result,$i,"outline")=="") ) {
            print "<b>No syllabus, or incomplete</b></td>";
        }
    } else {
        print "Based on $reference";
    }
    print "</td><td>$updated</td>\n";
        print "</tr>\n";  
        $i++;
}

print "</table>";

    exit;
}

$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE id = '$course_id'";

$result = mssql_query($sqlquery);
$number = mssql_num_rows($result);

if ($number == 0) {
print "<html><body>";
print "No course with the ID \"$course_id\" exists in the course database.";
print "</body></html>";
exit;
}

$i = 0;

$description = fromhtml(mssql_result($result,$i,"description"));
print "<html><head><title>DACC Course Syllabus - $course_id</title>";

print "<script language=\"JavaScript\" type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/rte/richtext2.js\"></script>";
?>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--    
initRTE("/rte/images/", "/rte/", "");
//-->   

function submitForm() {
   updateRTEs();
   document.edit-course.submit();
   return false;
}
</script>
<?php   
print "</head><body>\n";

//Begin Form
print "<form name=\"edit-course\" id=\"edit-form\" method=\"post\" action=\"write.php?course=$course_id\" onSubmit=\"return submitForm()\">\n";


print "<fieldset>";
 print "<label for=\"description\">Course Description</label>";
$description=addslashes(preg_replace('`[\r\n]`','',$description));
  ?>
   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
  writeRichText('description', '<?php print $description; ?>', 200, 300, true, false);
//-->
</script>
  <?php

   print "</fieldset>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It that BR is at very very beginning of string then use this

```
$x = preg_replace("/^<br(\/|)>/i","\n",$x);
```

instead of that commented line

Comment: Minimihi you are a genius!!! thank you so much I have been struggling with this for months!

Comment: Whoa! Your're making me blush

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace` has a fourth parameter, `$limit`. Setting this to 1 would limit the preg_replace to the first occurence. Alternatively you could use the regular expression `^<br>`. This would only replace `<br>` when it is at the beginning of the string.

Edit: Sorry, I misunderstood your problem. Use `$variable=preg_replace("/^<br>/i", "", $variable);` to strip the first `<br>`.