# PHP form inserting <br> at the end of the text on each submission to MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server

Hi everyone I had previously posted about a `<br>` getting inserted at the beginning of my text and we got that fixed. ([here is my previous post with the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409583/form-submission-adds-a-br-in-front-of-the-beginning-text-in-the-form)) I changed the code as suggested from

```
$x = preg_replace("/<br>/i","\n",$x);
```

to

```
   $x = preg_replace("/^<br(\/|)>/i","\n",$x);
```

which worked to stop the `<br>` from being inserted at the beginning but now it is inserting one at the end. How do I stop that from happening?

**SOLUTION**

`$x = preg_replace("/^<br(\/|)>/i","\n",$x);`
Jacks solution--- `//$x = preg_replace('#^<br(\/|)>+|<br(\/|)>+$#i', "\n", $x);`
My fix in addition to the original preg_replace

`$x= preg_replace("/(^)?(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+$/","\n", $x);`

**UPDATE**

it is no longer adding `<br>` each time it is submitted but there are now two`<br>` after the text that only show up in the database and are not brought out in the editor. I need to get rid of these breaks!

Comment: If you remove the `^` in the front, it'll remove all `<br>` tags, regardless of position.  If that's overkill, just add a second replacement using `/<br(\/|)>$/i` as the pattern.

Comment: Giga, thanks for your reply I tried this and it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, matches `<br>`, `<br/>` or `<br />` at the start or end:

```
preg_replace('#^<br(\s*/)?>|<br(\s*/)?>$#i', "\n", $str);
```

The tag is matched by:
* Literal `<br`
* Optional spaces followed by a forward slash

The `|` in the middle is used to denote an alternative condition (i.e. `OR`).

**Edit**

Instead of `<br(\s*/)?>` you can also write `<br(\/|)>` that you had before.

**Edit 2**

Multiple occurrences can be matched by just adding `+` behind each pattern:

```
preg_replace('#^<br(\/|)>+|<br(\/|)>+$#i', "\n", $str);
```

Comment: does `#` stand for `/` in preg_replace?

Comment: @ZathrusWriter Yes, the first character is taken as the expression boundary, but you can also wrap your RegEx inside `{` and `}` if you want :)

Comment: Thank you I shall give this a try :)

Comment: Still adds the < br> at the end

Comment: @Inky1231 no, the `?` has to be there, but do I see correctly that you have `< br>` at the end?

Comment: yes every time I submit the form it inserts a `<br>` at teh end of the string  The < br> is because I couldn't figure out how to post `<br>` tags here there is no space in my code

Comment: the ?> in the preg_replace ends up breaking it out of PHP so the second half is not in PHP)

Comment: @Inky1231 I assure you that it runs fine in PHP; perhaps your editor can't take the `?>` inside string context :)

Comment: it's possible, I am using expressionweb...which I hate!

Comment: Ok I just tried to run it with that in there, first submission no `<br>` second submission the `<br>` is there

Comment: your updated answer fixed it so EW doesn't scream at me :D but it still puts a `<br>` in on the second submission and subsequent submissions

Comment: 1 each time it is submitted, so if I submit a second item now there are two etc... this is a form for editing syllabi so some get edited a half dozen items or more. can mess up the look of the page big time.

Comment: @Jack- no go still put it in at the end. I will keep playing with it maybe I will figure out why. Thanks for being patient with me and helping me out!