# PHP SQL `<br>` tags mysteriously appearing in database

Tags: php, sql

I was having trouble with a form that was inserting a `<br>` at the end of the text in a text area and it would insert a new break upon each submission. When I would enter the editor again those breaks would be visible. I inserted the following code and it seemed to work, the `<br>`s were no longer multiplying or showing up in the editor.

```
 $x = preg_replace("/^<br(\/|)>/i","\n",$x);
 $x = preg_replace("/(^)?(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+$/","\n", $x);
```

However, now it is entering two `<br>` tags at the end of the text when it puts it into SQL.

My previous post about this is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677688/php-form-inserting-br-at-the-end-of-the-text-on-each-submission-to-mssql).

**Edited to include code up to the form info**

```
<?php

include ("main_fns.php"); // This file would include your database access and login     functions, include this at the top of EVERY page, in order to carry the session     between pages and access the database.
open_db(); // Open a database connection

$page_file = "sample.php"; // the file name of this page
$page_title = "Course Admin Area"; // can be fed into the header

include ("header.php");

// Check for logged in session variable, else prompt for login.
if (!@$_SESSION["email"]) {
loginPrompt(@$_POST["email"],$_SESSION["error"]);
} else {

// PAGE CONTENT GOES HERE

function fromhtml ($x) {
$x = preg_replace("/<p>/i","\n\n",$x);
$x = preg_replace("/^<br(\/|)>/i","\n",$x);
$x = preg_replace("/<li>/i","\n<li>",$x);
$x= preg_replace("/(^)?(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+$/","\n", $x); 
return $x;
}




$DBhost = "localhost";
$DBuser = "daccweb";
$DBpass = "go";
$DBName = "DACC";
mssql_connect($DBhost,$DBuser,$DBpass) or die("Unable to connect to database");
@mssql_select_db("$DBName") or die("Unable to select database $DBName");


$PHP_SELF = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];


$course_id = @$_GET["course"];

if ($course_id == "") {
//$sqlquery = "SELECT id,title,goals,outline,reference,DATE_FORMAT(updated, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%S') as         updated2 FROM courses WHERE division_id = '$division_id' ORDER BY id";
$sqlquery = "SELECT id, title, goals, outline, reference, deliverymode, updated2 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),     updated, 120)
FROM courses WHERE division_id = '$division_id' ORDER by id";


$result = mssql_query($sqlquery);
$number = mssql_num_rows($result);

if ($number == 0) {
        print "<html><body>";
        print "No courses exist for division $division_id.";
        print "</body></html>";
    exit;
}

print "<b>Course list - division $division_id</b><p>\n";
print "Select a course ID to edit course information.<p>\n";
print "<table border=1 id=\"content_table\"><tr><th>ID</th><th>Title</th><th>Status</th><th>Last modified</th></tr>\n";

$i = 0;
while ($number > $i) {

        $course_id =  mssql_result($result,$i,"id");
    $reference = mssql_result($result,$i,"reference");
    $updated = mssql_result($result,$i,"updated2");

    print "<tr><td>";
    if ($reference == "") {
            print "<a href=$PHP_SELF?division=$division_id&course=$course_id>$course_id</a>";
    } else {
            print "$course_id";
    }
    print "</td><td>";
        print mssql_result($result,$i,"title");
    print "</td><td>";
    if ($reference == "") {
        if ( (mssql_result($result,$i,"goals")=="") and (mssql_result($result,$i,"outline")=="")     ) {
            print "<b>No syllabus, or incomplete</b></td>";
        }
    } else {
        print "Based on $reference";
    }
    print "</td><td>$updated</td>\n";
        print "</tr>\n";  
        $i++;
}

print "</table>";

    exit;
}

$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE id = '$course_id'";

$result = mssql_query($sqlquery);
$number = mssql_num_rows($result);

if ($number == 0) {
print "<html><body>";
print "No course with the ID \"$course_id\" exists in the course database.";
print "</body></html>";
exit;
}

$i = 0;
$title = fromhtml(mssql_result($result,$i,"title"));
$iai = fromhtml(mssql_result($result,$i,"iai"));
$deliverymode = fromhtml(mssql_result($result,$i,"deliverymode"));
$hours = fromhtml(mssql_result($result,$i,"hours"));
$type = fromhtml(mssql_result($result,$i,"type"));
$description = fromhtml(mssql_result($result,$i,"description"));
$semester = fromhtml(mssql_result($result,$i,"semester"));
$prerequisites =fromhtml(mssql_result($result,$i,"prerequisites"));
$notes = fromhtml(mssql_result($result,$i,"notes"));
$goals = fromhtml(mssql_result($result,$i,"goals"));
$outline = fromhtml(mssql_result($result,$i,"outline"));
$materials = fromhtml(mssql_result($result,$i,"materials"));
$evaluation = fromhtml(mssql_result($result,$i,"evaluation"));
$bibliography = fromhtml(mssql_result($result,$i,"bibliography"));
$revised = mssql_result($result,$i,"revised");

print "<html><head><title>DACC Course Syllabus - $course_id</title>";

print "<script language=\"JavaScript\" type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/rte/richtext2.js\"></script>";
?>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--    
initRTE("/rte/images/", "/rte/", "");
//-->   

function submitForm() {
   updateRTEs();
   document.edit-course.submit();
   return false;
}

</script>

<?php   

print "</head><body>\n";

print "<a href=/courses/$division_id>Back to the $division_id course list</a>";
```

Comment: Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you į̷̷͚̤̤̖̱̦͍͗̒̈̅̄̎n̨͖͓̹͍͎͔͈̝̲͐ͪ͛̃̄͛ṣ̷̵̞̦ͤ̅̉̋ͪ͑͛ͥ͜a̷̘͖̮͔͎͛̇̏̒͆̆͘n͇͔̤̼͙̩͖̭ͤ͋̉͌͟eͥ͒͆ͧͨ̽͞҉̹͍̳̻͢](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) instead.

Comment: I didn't build this page I am trying to fix it though

Comment: Where is your RegEx in relation to your SQL insert? I think we need to see more of your code.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha An HTML parser to replace a few `<br>` tags? That's probably worse than regex.

Comment: @NullUserException: I'd still prefer that over RegEx in this case. There're too many premutations that may affect the `<br>`.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha No, there aren't. `~<br\s*/?>~i` is all you need. That's something you can do with one line of regex.

Comment: @ThomasLangston I edited to include most of the code I left out the form info.

Comment: @Inky1231 Replace both your regex calls to replace newlines with `preg_replace('~<br\s*/?>~i', "\n", $x)` and tell me what you get.

Comment: @NullUserException I did as you suggested and the extra `<br>` are still being put in.

Comment: @NullUserException: `<br>`s may have spaces before the tag name, as well as attributes

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Not if you are dealing with predictable input.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha these ones don't they are somehow being put in between hitting update record and the SQL database the text in the database looks like this "Some sentence here.`<br><br>`

Comment: I do have `$description=addslashes(preg_replace('`[\r\n]`','',$description));` before each text area as per the RTE instructions. However I don't think this is  the cause as before putting the Regex in it would add one new `<br>` per submission and would show in the editor