# PHP, SQL form inserts `<br>` into blank field, how do I remove it without removing all `<BR>` in the entire form

Tags: php, sql

OK I have posted two other topics about these darn `<br>` [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409583/form-submission-adds-a-br-in-front-of-the-beginning-text-in-the-form) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677688/php-form-inserting-br-at-the-end-of-the-text-on-each-submission-to-mssql)  I got the form to stop putting in a new 
 at teh beginning and end of text in the text areas with the following code

```
function fromhtml ($x) {
$x = preg_replace("/<p>/i","\n\n",$x);
$x = preg_replace("/^<br(\/|)>/i","\n",$x);
//$x = preg_replace('#^<br(\/|)>+|<br(\/|)>+$#i', "\n", $x);
$x= preg_replace("/(^)?(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+$/","\n", $x);
$x = preg_replace("/<li>/i","\n<li>",$x);

return $x;
}
```

Now the problem I am having is that on fields that are left empty a `<br>` gets inserted into the field on submission. It doesn't repeat but that one `<br>` can be a problem on some fields as there is a conditional statement about printing that field on another page. any help would be appreciated.

EDITED to add the conditional statement from the other page

```
if ($prerequisites != "") {
        print " <b>Prerequisites:</b> ".link_course($prerequisites);
    }
```

Comment: how about `if($x=='<br>') { $x=''; }` ? Or do I not understand the problem?

Comment: Are you talking about putting that in the conditional statement on the other page?

Comment: Not sure, I posted this before your edit. Is the `<BR>` being added before or after you run fromhtml()? If after, you can just put that line in the function.

Comment: It's being added when you submit the form to the SQL database. I remove the `<br>` tag from the text area and then submit the form when I pull up the form to edit the information the `<br>` tag is back.

Comment: tried putting yoru suggestion in the function and that didn't work.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the record in the database actually has "<BR>" in it? Or is it possible that the database has a blank record, but when the application retrieves a blank record, it replaces it with "<BR>"?

Comment: OK the database record does have a `<br>` in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply check if the string is a br, and if so replace it with ''

```
function fromhtml ($x) {
    $x = preg_replace("/<p>/i","\n\n",$x);
    $x = preg_replace("/^<br(\/|)>/i","\n",$x);
    $x= preg_replace("/(^)?(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+$/","\n", $x);
    $x = preg_replace("/<li>/i","\n<li>",$x);
    if(trim(strtolower($x))=="<br>")
        return "";
    return $x;
}
```

Comment: did you tried adding this just before the "return $x" in your code?

Comment: I tried both `function fromhtml ($x) {
$x = preg_replace("/<p>/i","\n\n",$x);
$x = preg_replace("/^<br(\/|)>/i","\n",$x);
//$x = preg_replace('#^<br(\/|)>+|<br(\/|)>+$#i', "\n", $x);
$x= preg_replace("/(^)?(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+$/","\n", $x);
$x = preg_replace("/<li>/i","\n<li>",$x);

return $x;
}
function clearText($x)
{
    if(trim($x)=="<br>")
        return "";
    return $x;
}`
' which did not work

Comment: Replace in your code "return $x" with this: if(trim($x)=="<br>")
        return "";
    return $x;

Comment: and `function fromhtml ($x) {
$x = preg_replace("/<p>/i","\n\n",$x);
$x = preg_replace("/^<br(\/|)>/i","\n",$x);
//$x = preg_replace('#^<br(\/|)>+|<br(\/|)>+$#i', "\n", $x);
$x= preg_replace("/(^)?(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+$/","\n", $x);
$x = preg_replace("/<li>/i","\n<li>",$x);
function clearText($x)
{
    if(trim($x)=="<br>")
        return "";
    return $x;
}

return $x;
}
` which gave me an error

Comment: replacing the "return $x" with the `<br>` says unexpected <

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17519/discussion-between-roberto-and-inky1231)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your form, not specifically with PHP. Textarea tags use any data contained within them as the input, so if your tags are separated by a line-break, that is on two different lines in the html served, then the form submit will report an html line-break is present in the Textarea. This is easily correctable by keeping the tags on the same line.

Regardless, you are probably better with str_replace to get rid of excess line-breaks, so :

```
str_replace("<br>", "", str_replace("<br/>", "", str_replace("</br>", "", $x)));
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use `$your_string = strip_tags($your_string)` before inserting